# What attributes are updated in waterline afterUpdate?

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I use Sails.js (0.10.5) with waterline (sails-postgresql 0.10.14). 
In e.g. User model, the afterUpdate trigger return the whole user object. Is there any possibility to get what attributes are updated?

Comment: are you asking for just the attributes that were changed or all the attributes that were past to the model?

Comment: Just the attributes what were changed.